# Make equal distance for bars with different width Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I made a drilldown bar chart where the bars have different pointWidth.I want to have different widths for each bar because they have different percentage range.
But after I drew it, I found they have regular interval but uneven distribution. The blank space between bars are not equally and I cannot see all the bars.

I also tried pointPadding, but I still feel the space between the bars is too wide.So I decided to use pointwidth in this code in order to customize bar width.

I wonder how to make the interval between them equally so I can see all the bars aligning perfectly. Or maybe using pointPadding but shorten the blank space between bars.

Here is the code.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Demo Demo Demo',
    margin:50
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Percentage Range"
    }
  },
  yAix: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Number of Schools"
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      grouping: false,//divide series into three individual series 
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.1,
    pointWidth:27.24, 
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
      name: '100-97%',
      y: 50,
      color: "#E96A50",
      drilldown: '100-97%',
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.1,
     pointWidth:18.16,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
      name: '97-95%',
            y: 33,
            color: "#E96A50",
            drilldown: '97-95%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.4,
    pointWidth:18.16,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
      name: '95-93%',
            y: 33,
            color: "#E96A50",
            drilldown: '95-93%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.4,
    pointWidth:27.24,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
       name: '93-90%',
            y: 24,
            color: "#E96A50",
            drilldown: '93-90%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointWidth:90.8,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
         name: '90-80%',
            y: 42,
            color: "#F2B04E",
            drilldown: '90-80%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointWidth:90.8,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
         name: '80-70%',
            y: 12,
            color: "#F2B04E",
            drilldown: '80-70%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0,
    pointWidth:272,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
         name: '70-40%',
            y: 36,
            color: "#80AB7F",
            drilldown: '70-40%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0,
    pointWidth:272,
    tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
        pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
    data: [{
         name: '40-10%',
            y: 37,
            color: "#284E62",
            drilldown: '40-10%'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    //drillUpButton Option
         drillUpButton: {
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                y: 10,
                x: 0
            },
            theme: {
               color: "#5ab7f5",
                fill: 'white',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: '#5ab7f5',
                r: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fill: '#5ab7f5'
                    },
                    select: { 
                        fill: '#5ab7f5'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    series: [{id:"100-97%", data: [
    ["Global Education Academy Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",100],
    ["Public Policy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",100],
    ["N.E.W. Academy of Science and Arts (Los Angeles Unified)",99.9],
    ["Puente Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",99.7],
    ["Alliance College-Ready Middle Academy 4 (Los Angeles Unified)",99.4]
]}, {id:"97-95%", data:[
["Aspire Juanita Tate Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",96.9],
    ["Summit Preparatory Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",96.9],
    ["Animo College Preparatory Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",96.9],
    ["Alliance Ouchi-O'Donovan 6-12 Complex (Los Angeles Unified)",96.9],
    ["Animo Ellen Ochoa Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",96.9]
]}, {id:"95-93%", data:[
    ["Celerity Octavia Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",94.9],
    ["KIPP Vida Preparatory Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",94.8],
    ["Aspire Pacific Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",94.8],
    ["Vista Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",94.8],
    ["Aspire Junior Collegiate Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",94.7]
]},{id:"93-90%", data: [
    ["Aspire Firestone Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",92.9],
    ["USC East College Prep (Los Angeles Unified)",92.8],
    ["Collegiate Charter High School of Los Angeles (Los Angeles Unified)",92.6],
    ["KIPP Sol Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",92.6],
    ["Alliance Leadership Middle Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",92.5]
]},
{id:"90-80%", data: [
    ["KIPP Iluminar Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",89.8],
    ["Rise Kohyang Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",89.8],
    ["Los Angeles Leadership Primary Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",89.6],
    ["KIPP Empower Academy (Los Angeles Unified)",89.6],
    ["Lou Dantzler Preparatory Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",89.6],
]},
{id:"80-70%", data:[
    ["Fenton Academy for Social and Emotional Learning (Los Angeles Unified)",79.9],
    ["Magnolia Science Academy 7 (Los Angeles Unified)",79.6],
    ["New Millennium Secondary (Los Angeles Unified)",78.7],
    ["PUC Community Charter Middle and PUC Community Charter Early College High (Los Angeles Unified)",77.4],
    ["Animo Westside Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",76.4],
  
    ]},
{id:"70-40%", data: [
    
    ["Emelita Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",68.7],
    ["View Park Preparatory Accelerated High (Los Angeles Unified)",67.5],
    ["Metro Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",66.8],
    ["Calvert Charter for Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)",66.2],
    ["Grover Cleveland Charter High (Los Angeles Unified)",66.1],
]},{id:"40-10%", data: [
    ["Robert A. Millikan Middle School, Performing Arts Magnet & Science Academy STEM (Los Angeles Unified)",39.3],
    ["Darby Avenue Charter (Los Angeles Unified)",38.6],
    ["Westside Innovative School House Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)",38.6],
    ["El Oro Way Charter For Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)",36.3],
    ["Serrania Avenue Charter For Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)",36.1],
  

]}]
  }
});
```

```css
.highcharts-drillup-button text tspan{
  fill:  #5ab7f5;
}

.highcharts-drillup-button:hover text tspan{
  fill:  white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: In addition to the answer posted by @Deep 3015, you can use pointPlacement property to increase/decrease space between columns. Example: jsfiddle.net/7vn1nqm0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dedicated region in the chart where the columns are rendered.If that column width is increased then it will overlap each other.So safe side use `pointPadding` to give desired width with in region. So again coming to *shorten the blank space between bars* this is also not possible as mentioned above.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Demo Demo Demo',
    margin: 50
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Percentage Range"
    }
  },
  yAix: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Number of Schools"
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      grouping: false, //divide series into three individual series ,

      groupPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    // pointPadding: 0.1,
    pointWidth: 27.24,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '100-97%',
      y: 50,
      color: "#E96A50",
      drilldown: '100-97%',
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.1,
    //pointWidth:18.16,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '97-95%',
      y: 33,
      color: "#E96A50",
      drilldown: '97-95%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.4,
    //pointWidth:18.16,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '95-93%',
      y: 33,
      color: "#E96A50",
      drilldown: '95-93%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.4,
    //pointWidth:27.24,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '93-90%',
      y: 24,
      color: "#E96A50",
      drilldown: '93-90%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    //pointWidth:90.8,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '90-80%',
      y: 42,
      color: "#F2B04E",
      drilldown: '90-80%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    //pointWidth:90.8,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '80-70%',
      y: 12,
      color: "#F2B04E",
      drilldown: '80-70%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0,
    //pointWidth:272,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '70-40%',
      y: 36,
      color: "#80AB7F",
      drilldown: '70-40%'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Number of Schools',
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointPadding: 0,
    //pointWidth:272,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span><strong>Percentage Arange: {point.key}</strong></span>',
      pointFormat: '<br><span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    data: [{
      name: '40-10%',
      y: 37,
      color: "#284E62",
      drilldown: '40-10%'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    //drillUpButton Option
    drillUpButton: {
      relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
      position: {
        y: 10,
        x: 0
      },
      theme: {
        color: "#5ab7f5",
        fill: 'white',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: '#5ab7f5',
        r: 5,
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: 'white',
            fill: '#5ab7f5'
          },
          select: {
            fill: '#5ab7f5'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        id: "100-97%",
        data: [
          ["Global Education Academy Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 100],
          ["Public Policy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 100],
          ["N.E.W. Academy of Science and Arts (Los Angeles Unified)", 99.9],
          ["Puente Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 99.7],
          ["Alliance College-Ready Middle Academy 4 (Los Angeles Unified)", 99.4]
        ]
      }, {
        id: "97-95%",
        data: [
          ["Aspire Juanita Tate Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 96.9],
          ["Summit Preparatory Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 96.9],
          ["Animo College Preparatory Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 96.9],
          ["Alliance Ouchi-O'Donovan 6-12 Complex (Los Angeles Unified)", 96.9],
          ["Animo Ellen Ochoa Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 96.9]
        ]
      }, {
        id: "95-93%",
        data: [
          ["Celerity Octavia Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 94.9],
          ["KIPP Vida Preparatory Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 94.8],
          ["Aspire Pacific Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 94.8],
          ["Vista Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 94.8],
          ["Aspire Junior Collegiate Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 94.7]
        ]
      }, {
        id: "93-90%",
        data: [
          ["Aspire Firestone Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 92.9],
          ["USC East College Prep (Los Angeles Unified)", 92.8],
          ["Collegiate Charter High School of Los Angeles (Los Angeles Unified)", 92.6],
          ["KIPP Sol Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 92.6],
          ["Alliance Leadership Middle Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 92.5]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "90-80%",
        data: [
          ["KIPP Iluminar Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 89.8],
          ["Rise Kohyang Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 89.8],
          ["Los Angeles Leadership Primary Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 89.6],
          ["KIPP Empower Academy (Los Angeles Unified)", 89.6],
          ["Lou Dantzler Preparatory Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 89.6],
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "80-70%",
        data: [
          ["Fenton Academy for Social and Emotional Learning (Los Angeles Unified)", 79.9],
          ["Magnolia Science Academy 7 (Los Angeles Unified)", 79.6],
          ["New Millennium Secondary (Los Angeles Unified)", 78.7],
          ["PUC Community Charter Middle and PUC Community Charter Early College High (Los Angeles Unified)", 77.4],
          ["Animo Westside Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 76.4],

        ]
      },
      {
        id: "70-40%",
        data: [

          ["Emelita Academy Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 68.7],
          ["View Park Preparatory Accelerated High (Los Angeles Unified)", 67.5],
          ["Metro Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 66.8],
          ["Calvert Charter for Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)", 66.2],
          ["Grover Cleveland Charter High (Los Angeles Unified)", 66.1],
        ]
      }, {
        id: "40-10%",
        data: [
          ["Robert A. Millikan Middle School, Performing Arts Magnet & Science Academy STEM (Los Angeles Unified)", 39.3],
          ["Darby Avenue Charter (Los Angeles Unified)", 38.6],
          ["Westside Innovative School House Charter Middle (Los Angeles Unified)", 38.6],
          ["El Oro Way Charter For Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)", 36.3],
          ["Serrania Avenue Charter For Enriched Studies (Los Angeles Unified)", 36.1],


        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.highcharts-drillup-button text tspan {
  fill: #5ab7f5;
}

.highcharts-drillup-button:hover text tspan {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```